# Grammar where tokens can be transmuted

Tags: formal-grammars

I have a grammar which is mostly `LL(1)`, save for the fact that some tokens may be promoted to larger integer types.

For example, let take the following grammar

```
S ::= terminal1 S1
S1 ::= integer_16 S2 | integer_32 S3
```

where `S2` and `S3` can share a common prefix but we assume the above grammar can be rewritten as `LL(1)`, save for the integer promotion and that the narrowest numbers have precedence over the the wider numbers.

Let's assume that I read an `integer_16` but fail to match `S2`, I'll backtrack and promote `integer_16` to `integer_32`. This can be easily done when doing error-recovery by adding a case for non-fatal error if the token can be promoted.

This is a special case of `LL(k)` grammar, but my question is does such grammars (`LL(1)`+some dirty error-recovery tricks) have a standard name?

Answer (score 1):

The type of a literal integer is semantic, not syntactic, and should not be part of syntactic analysis. In other words, the program text can be *parsed* -- broken into syntactic parts with known relationships -- without knowing the magnitude of each integer literal. The magnitude of the literal does not affect the literal's syntactic role; the operand of an multiplication does not transform itself into an operand of an adjacent addition if it becomes greater. In other words, `x + y * z always means the sum of` x`and the product of`y`and`z`, no matter what the magnitudes of the three values might be. (At least, I hope that's true of your language. If it isn't, composing correct code would be a difficult undertaking.)

You might argue that some choices of value lead to invalid code, for example in a language without automatic widening conversions. Certainly, some semantic errors can be statically detected; others cannot. But that's not the goal of the parser. Type analysis and validation (or rejection) of type conversions are semantic operations, whether done in a semantic action or in a post-parse walk over the parse tree.

The key to writing a maintainable parser is to respect the principle of separation of concerns. A lexical analyser splits the input into tokens; nothing else. A parser creates the hierarchical structure of the program as a graph (usually a tree, at least in the first instance), and nothing else. A type-checker discovers and validates the semantic type of each component of an expression. And so on. Separation of concerns makes your programs easier to read, easier to debug, and easier to maintain.

Of course, nothing is totally pure. Your lexical analyser might convert each numeric literal into some internal representation of a number, and there might be different possible representations: different widths, different precisions, and so on. That might turn out to be a useful optimisation, instead of keeping them as character strings, for any of a number of reasons. But it's a trade-off: you will also have to deal with literals not using the representation which program semantics require, which I think is the basis of your question. Coping with that might complicate your code (or not, depending on the language your compiler is written in), in which case you might reasonably consider whether the optimisation justifies the complication. Sometimes, it turns out that it doesn't. Particularly at the beginning, it's often good to always choose the simplest implementation over the most efficient.

Regardless, it has nothing to do with parsing theory; LL(1) is LL(1), no matter what the semantics might be.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! I have also thought of performing type analysis but here, the magnitude of the literal has a syntactic role. Depending on the magnitude, the token has a completely different meaning, and can produce different derivations.